# Is there a language that supports implicit composite types at variable declaration?

Tags: java, c#

This question is more general and extends to typed non-OOP languages, but just to have code to demonstrate my intention I'm going to stick to a standard curly-brace language like C#.

The OOP languages I've seen support both composite interfaces

```
interface ISyntaxNode : ISyntax, INode {}
ISyntaxNode node;
// Do stuff with node
```

And also some notion of composite class

```
class SyntaxNode {
    // Members are public/private/partially exposed/whatever
    ISyntax code;
    INode node;
}
SyntaxNode node;
// Do stuff with node
```

But in both cases one needs to explicitly define the composite type and how it might behave before using it. Are there any languages that support some notion of *implicit* composite typing? E.g.

```
ISyntax INode node;
```

This would be a bit more useful/flexible in a language with a notion of implicit interfaces so that you could later define something like `ISyntaxNode` and still have `node` be one of those without any changes to the code, but I'm curious if that's a pattern anyone has seen in the wild. My google-foo has come up a little short trying to answer this question.

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is a tuple, which is provided in many languages.

Comment: @JoeC In the case of the composite class, I mostly agree other than perhaps with how the syntax would look. Hadn't thought about that. What about the composite interface though? Then you're really saying that you have a single object implementing both interfaces, not that you have two distinct objects.

Comment: Scala offers something called compound types where the types can be enumerated when declaring a variable/parameter something like this `val myVal: Type1 with Type2 with TypeN`. More details here [Compound types in Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/compound-types.html)

Comment: @ValentinCarnu Oh, neat. That looks like it's exactly what I was looking for, and it seems to be pretty much restricted to interface-like things (I don't know Scala yet), which is sort of what I expected. If you want to type that up into an answer I'll accept that and use it as a jumping-off point for the rest of my research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Compound Types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/compound-types.html) from Scala are very similar with what you are describing. The compound types allows to enumerate the types when declaring a variable/parameter

```
val myVal: Type1 with Type2 with TypeN = new Type1 with Type2 with TypeN
```